# Sending an Autoresponder/Email from GetResponse using PHP via Getresponse API

Tags: php, email, getresponse

Im doing a custome program where I will be inviting people to my site, based on their activities they get credits(just measuring points on their activeness) and based on the credits I need to send them emails, if they reach 100credits I need to send one email, and if they reach 1000 then some other email.

I want to do this via GetResponse API, Im new to GetResponse, can some one suggest me how to do this? is there any best way to achieve this via API using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider 'goals' feature from GetResponse. If you set on your website certain goals for different activities and then setup autoresponders based on those goals, then your customers will receive messages after complete some goal... The best thing is you don't need API for that, you can set up everything using GetResponse web panel.